# Why is there a small space between my navigation bar and my main picture?

Tags: html, css

I am currently making a website for myself and can't seem to figure out why there is a small space between the end of my navigation bar and the big picture (start of the content).

I also couldn't get the JSFiddle file to work for some reason.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Mobile Navigation -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/images/logo1.png" alt=""></a>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="hvr-underline-from-center">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" class="hvr-underline-from-center">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="hvr-underline-from-center">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" class="hvr-underline-from-center">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- End Navigation Bar -->


<header class="mainHeader" style="background-image: url('http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg');">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="siteContent">
      <h1>Some awesome text about this site!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #ece8e5;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-family: 'Monda', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

html {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-default {
  border-color: transparent !important;
  background-color: #303030 !important;
  height: 120px !important;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  color: #ddd !important;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 45px;
  margin: 1 !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar ul li {
  padding-left: 12px !important;
  padding-right: 12px !important;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}

a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.mainHeader {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Also note that the image being used is not the image for the website.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention it, but looking at your code I suppose you are using Bootstrap.
The .navbar is defined by default with 20px of bottom margin, so you should either customize you bootstrap before compiling it 
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ 
or just go for one more css line

```
.navbar {margin-bottom:0;}
```

you wrote

> I also couldn't get the JSFiddle file to work for some reason

It did work for me, so I'm wondering if you forgot to include bootstrap css in the "External Resources" tab of JSFiddle

Comment: This worked, thank you! I also did forget to include the bootstrap css in JSFiddle :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar has a bottom margin of 20. Change it to 0 with the below:

```
.navbar-default {
    border-color: transparent !important;
    background-color: #303030 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For error like this, you can use a "inspector" to determine which are the element that cause the problem and figure out how to fix ;)